# How to access the original error message created by the throw new Error() method?

Tags: node.js, error-handling

I created a custom error like this.

```
throw new Error(`The Nodal Officer ${nodalOfficerId} already exist`);
```

Using Node.js, how can I access the original error message inside the Error object, so that I can console that only, not the huge pile of the entire error stack.

Answer (score 2):

The `Error` class has a `message` property which refers to the description argument of the `Error`.

```js
try {
    throw new Error("The Nodal Officer (id) already exists");
} catch (e) {
    console.log("Error!", e.message);
    // should log "Error! The Nodal Officer (id) already exists"
}
```